# Weak convergence of integral with weak convergent integrand

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Suppose that $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded, $f_n(t,x)$, $g_n(t,x)$ are sequences such that
$$ \sup_{t\in[0,T]}\|f_n(t,\cdot)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}+\|g_n(t,\cdot)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq 1, $$
$$ f_n(t,x) = 1+\int_0^tg_n(s,x)ds.$$
Then, we can find subsequence such that $f_n$ and $g_n$ are weakly convergent to some $f^*$ and $g^*$ in $L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$. How can we know that for a.e. $t \in [0,T]$ and $x \in \Omega$,
$$ f^*(t,x) = 1+\int_0^tg^*(s,x)ds?$$

Comment: The functions $f^*$ and $g^*$ are actually in $L^\infty(0,T;L^2)$, as you can use weak-* convergence. Ideally you would like to take limits in both sides of the first equality as $n\to\infty$. The left hand side converges to $f^*$ in, say, the sense of distributions (up to subsequences). What can you say about the right hand side? Does it converge distributionally to the right hand side of the second equality? Once you prove this, you are clearly done. To prove it, integrate it against a test function,…

Comment: Do you mean the weak* convergence that $\int^T_0 \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f_n h \to \int^T_0  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}  f^* h $? And we think $f_n$ as a linear functional on $L^1$ in a way that $f_n :h \longmapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f_n h$?

Comment: They are linear functionals on $L^1(0,T;L^2)$. So, $f_n\colon h\mapsto \int_0^T\int_{\mathbb R^n} f_nh$

Comment: Yes, I missed the time integral accidentally. For the right-hand side, I consider the term $\int^T_0 \int^T_0\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g_n(s,x) \chi_{[0,t]}(s) h(t,x) ds dt$. Since $g_n$ weak star converges to $g^*$, can we make sure that $g_n(s,x) \chi_{[0,t]}(s)$ still converges to $g^*(s,x) \chi_{[0,t]}(s)$ (suppose that $h$ is bounded first)?

Comment: Yes. Keep in mind that $h$ is a smooth, compactly supported function. You simply need an estimate of the form $|\iint_{\mathbb R^n\times (0,T)} h(\int_0^t (g_n-g^*)(s)ds) |\leq C\|g_n-g^*\|_{L^2L^2}\|h\|_{L^\infty L^\infty}$

Comment: I am confused why the RHS converges to zero, I think it only converges weakly, the RHS seems like strong convergence.

Comment: You are right, sorry. What you need here is that the operator $g\mapsto L(g):= \int_0^t g(s)ds$ is bounded from $L^2L^2$ to itself. It is sufficient because continuous linear maps preserve weak convergence, so if $g_n\to g^*$ weakly, then $L(g_n)\to L(g^*)$ weakly. To show that $L$ is bounded one can use Höldrer’s inequality; in fact, $L(g)$ lies in $L^\infty L^2$ if $g$ lies in $L^2L^2$